# Video not playing on iOS Safari - iphone 6s

Tags: html, ios, video, tags

I'm trying to get my mp4 video file to show up on my iPhone 6s Safari browser.  The video files seems to show up on my Mac laptop and Windows computer browsers like Chrome/Explorer/Firefox but when I upload to the server the video doesn't seem to show up even after I clear the cache on Safari on my phone.  This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<video videoWidth videoHeight loop>
  <source src="video/demoYVR.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Any suggestions an insight would be appreciated - Thanks :)

B

Answer (score 0):

If you can download the video download it then play it on your media player in your phone.

If you can't download it try downloading Google or Firefox on the App Store.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Nol4635.

Comment: I actually have the video.  I should clarify that I am putting a website together to hopefully work on all browsers accept the video tag that I mentioned:

Comment: <video videoWidth videoHeight loop>
  <source src="video/demoYVR.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: doesn't seem to render the video on with my iPhone 6 Safari browser.  I just have an empty div container there.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Another thing is I've used all the same syntax as the w3schools;       <video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
and I still can't get the video to show up on a mobile device